# Fast API css and images not loading on page

Tags: html, css, fastapi

I have a fast API server I am building, but the images and CSS files from the template I grabbed are refusing to show up.

**Fast API:**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, status, Response

import asyncio
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, StreamingResponse
from fastapi.requests import Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

#app.mount("/static",StaticFiles(directory="static",name = "static")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get("/index", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

The folders are set up as follows:

- Server.py
- Templates

  - index.html
  - css

    - template.css
  - img

    - img1
    - img2

There is a templates folder which hosts all of my web files the HTML is in there and inside also are folders for CSS and IMG. I run the code and receive an error that says: ""GET /css/tooplate-vertex.css HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found". Unsure where this is occurring and I am new to FastAPI, but if this isn't clear let me know.

Comment: what OS are you using? In Linux `Templates` and `templates` are different folders.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't keep the static files (i.e. css/images/etc.) in the same directory as your templates (which contain dynamically evaluated HTML). Since you've commented out the StaticFiles handler, there is no way to retrieve these files in your templates - The static handler is responsible for serving any files located under its path directly.

Create a directory named `static` on the same level as `templates` (not under it), then enable the static file handler:

```
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static", name="static")
```

You can then use the `url_for` function in your templates to refer to the location of any files under the static file handler dynamically. For example:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/foo.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

This will create the URL for the file `foo.min.css` located under `static` in your application's directory structure. This leaves you with this common structure instead:

```
server.py
templates/    
  index.html
static/
  css/
    template.css
  img/
    img1
    img2
```